# UIScrollView and Tabbar

Tags: ios

I have a UIScrollView which contains many different labels and other stuff. I scroll the uiScrollView to the bottom and then change the tab using tabbar at the bottom which is always visible. Then I switch back to the same view which contains UIScrollView. When I try to scroll to the top it stops in the middle. How can I reset the UIScrollView or maintain the scrolled position.

I am using iOS 6 for iPhone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
setContentOffset:animated:
```

This sets the offset from the content view’s origin that corresponds to the receiver’s origin.